# Any IDE with docstring helper?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking for an IDE similar to netbeans(for Java) which shows JAVA-DOCS as we type in the function name  :

[image: netbeans]

Is there a similar IDE for python that shows me the entire documentation: ?

I am not looking for something like ..help(str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you can use following one

> [Pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/index.html)
>
> [Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/products/studio3)
>
> [spyderlib](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/)